# Optimize $f(x,y,z) = xyz$ restricted to $g(x,y,z)= x^2+2y^2+3z^2= 6$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I'm stuck doing this problem.

**Optimize $f(x,y,z) = xyz$ restricted to $g(x,y,z) = x^2+2y^2+3z^2 = 6$**

First, I found ${\nabla}f$ and ${\lambda}{\nabla}g$, and for Lagrange Multipliers, I got these four equations

$$ \begin{matrix}
yz = 2{\lambda}x \hspace{8mm} (1) \\
xz = 4{\lambda}y \hspace{8mm} (2) \\
xy = 6{\lambda}z \hspace{8mm} (3) \\
x^2+2y^2+3z^2 = 6 \hspace{8mm} (4)
\end{matrix} $$

But I don't know how to find $x,y,z$ or $\lambda$. I've been trying by summing two of those equiations, but from the expressions I got (which are too complicated to write here) I don't know what to find first.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try multiplying equations 1,2 and 3 by x, y, and z respectively. Then the left hand sides will all be equal and you can work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ First check that $\lambda \neq 0$. Next multiply (1) by $x$ and (2) by $y$, you get:

$$xyz=2\lambda x^2$$

$$xyz=4 \lambda y^2$$

So $2 \lambda x^2=4 \lambda y^2$, then $x^2=2y^2$. The same with (1) and (3), next (2) and (3), finally substitute to (4).